# command to find files by searching only part of their names?

Tags: command-line, files, search, find

Say there are files with names:

```
batman.c
debate.c
cricketbat.c
```

What command and how should I use it to list all these files by using the searchtag `bat`?

Comment: Do you want to list matching files in only the current directory? in any directory at or below the current directory? anywhere on the system?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

#### Finding Files with `bat` Anywhere

To find all files anywhere inside `/path/to/folder` whose names contain `bat`, you can use:

```bash
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat*'
```

I have [quoted](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) the search pattern `*bat*` because, if the quotes were omitted and files match `*bat*` in the current directory, the shell will expand `*bat*` into a list of them and pass *that* to `find`. Then `find` wouldn't work right. (`\*bat\*` and `"*bat*"` also work.)

To search in the folder you're currently in (e.g., that you've `cd`ed to), use `.`, as usual:

```bash
find . -name '*bat*'
```

To search your whole computer, [use `/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory). To search your home directory, use `~`, or the full name of your home directory. ([The shell expands `~`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) to your home directory's fully qualified path.)

#### Broadening or Narrowing Your Search, Based on Name

If you want to search case-insensitively, so files containing `BAT`, `bAt`, and so forth are matched, use the `-iname` test instead of the `-name` test:

```bash
find /path/to/folder -iname '*bat*'
```

I've noticed all your files end in `.c`. If you only want to find files like that, use:

```bash
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat*.c'
```

I noticed all your filenames have `bat` either at the very beginning or the very end of the part preceding the `.c` suffix. If you want to avoid matching files like `embattled.c`, you could use:

```bash
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat.c' -o -name 'bat*.c'
```

`-o` is the *or* operator.

#### Matching Only Files

To find only [*regular files*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Regular_file)--and not folders, symbolic links, and special device nodes--you can use `-type f`. This is frequently recommended and sometimes quite appropriate... but **often not what you really want**, especially if you're running `find` for the purpose of examining the output yourself. If you had [a symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) that matched your search, wouldn't you want to know about it?

If you want to find both regular files and symbolic links, you can use:

```bash
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat*' \( -type f -o -type l \)
```

That uses the `-o` operator and also parentheses for grouping (which must be quoted so the shell does not treat them specially; otherwise you'll get a syntax error).

But suppose you only want to see symbolic links that ultimately point to a regular file (and not symbolic links to directories, device nodes, etc.). That's actually even simpler: use `-xtype` instead of `-type`. Provided you're not running `find` with `-L` flag, `-xtype` on a symbolic link tests the type of the file the link points to.

```bash
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat*' -xtype f
```

If you have a symlink to another symlink to a file, `-xtype f` will match it even though its *direct* target is another symlink rather than a regular file. This is almost always what you want.

Often people think they want `-type f`, but really they want `-xtype f`.

#### Getting Detailed Output

`find`'s default action if you don't specify one is `-print`. All the commands given above are equivalent to themselves with `-print` tacked on at the end.

`find` is often used to run commands based on the files found--often, commands that make changes. But there are also other actions whose purpose is to display results, besides `-print`. Of particular interest is `-ls`:

```
find /path/to/folder -name '*bat*' -ls
```

This gives detailed information on each file, in a multi-column format, similar to (though not quite the same as) what you would see by running `ls file`.

#### *Further Reading*

For more information on `find` and other ways to find files, see:

- [The `find` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/find.1.html), accessible online or by running `man find` in a terminal.
- The [GNU findutils reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html), providing extensive documentation on the `find`, `locate`, and `xargs` utilities.
- [FindingFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles) in the [Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/), which [shows how to use find](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles#find) as well as several other methods.

Comment: Great answer, especially the `-xtype` advice; perhaps `ls *bat*` and `-maxdepth` / `mindepth` are also worth mentioning.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks! The OP hasn't yet [provided clarification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621063/command-to-find-files-by-searching-only-part-of-their-names/621094?noredirect=1#comment878282_621063) about where the files are and whether or not recursion is needed. As [chaos's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621078) covered `ls` already, I focused on the recursive case with `find` here. Of course, a detailed answer covering non (or less)-recursive listing of filenames matching some pattern (`ls` and `find` with `-maxdepth`) would also be useful. You might want to post such an answer!

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to run

```
locate bat
```

This way you can search through the whole computer for files containing "bat" in the file name

To refresh the list of files on your PC run

```
updatedb
```

Run this command when you have recently added new files to your account

Comment: needs `updatetdb`

Comment: @Serg To find new files (newer than the last time `updatedb` was last manually or automatically run), `sudo updatedb` would need to be run first, yes.

Comment: Note that this will search the entire system for names matching `bat`.

Comment: @terdon I already stated this in the answer, don't think it deserved the down vote when I already stated this.

Comment: I was just making it clear to the OP. What downvote?

Comment: @terdon, sorry I assumed from your comment it was you who down voted from 2 to 1 must of been just a coincidence and it went back up a minuet ago, so don't know whats going on there.

Comment: Note that this is A LOT faster than `find /` as `locate` searches from a database, while `find` recursively lists `/` and then matches the regex.

Answer (score 15):

Open the terminal and change directories to the directory from where you want to start searching and then run this command:

```
find . -name "*bat*" -type f
```

The `.` starts  the find command from the current directory.
The `-name` matches the string `bat` and is case sensitive. (`-iname` is case insensitive)
The `-type f` searches for files only.

Comment: delete and undelete? ok +1 :P ;)

Answer (score 6):

If the files are in the current directory use:

```
$ ls *bat*
batgirl.c  batman.c  batwoman.c  cricketbat.c
```

Or (to have them line by line):

```
$ ls -1 *bat*
batgirl.c
batman.c
batwoman.c
cricketbat.c
```

If you want to search the system for that files, use:

```
$ find / -name "*bat*"
/path/to/cricketbat.c
/path/to/batgirl.c
/path/to/batwoman.c
/path/to/batman.c
```

Comment: If your search is starting with root directory, you might want to add sudo, as this command will report 'Permission denied' for some folders

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `find` command, with the `-iname` option for case insensitive file name matching, or the `-name` option for case sensitive file name matches. Both of these will let you use wildcard names. So, to find any file names which contain "bat" you would use:

```
find / -iname '*bat*'
```

Or

```
find / -name '*bat*'
```

The `*` means "any character(s)", so the search is looking for `bat` with any characters, including none, before or after it. The `/` searches from the root directory recursively, you can use `.` which will search recursively from the current directory, or the absolute path for where you want to search from.
Take a look at [how search for files using regex in linux shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791602/how-search-for-files-using-regex-in-linux-shell-script)

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks, I've added some more information to my answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the edit. IMO it is a strength of this answer that it *avoids* recommending the indiscriminate use of `-type f`, which does more than simply excluding directories and is [often not what users really want](https://askubuntu.com/a/621094/22949).

Answer (score 2):

Use the good old `find`.

```
find <path_for_search> -type f -iname "*bat*"
```

eg.:

```
% find . -type f -iname "*bat*" 
./batgirl.c
./batwoman.c
./cricketbat.c
./batman.c
```

from `man find`:

```
-type c
          File is of type c:
          [..]
          d      directory
          [..]
          f      regular file
          [..]

-iname pattern 
          Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.
```