# locate command finds a file's path, but the file does not exist in that path

Tags: find, ls, locate

I have written:

```
locate Origin90SR2DVD.iso
```

And I received the path where that file is located:

```
/home/david/Origin90SR2DVD.iso
```

Then I have written:

```
cd /home/david
```

I have run:

```
ls -lrth
```

And I cannot find the `Origin90SR2DVD.iso` file.

Why the file is not in that path?

Comment: What is the output of `locate Origin90SR2DVD.iso`?

Comment: @mkasberg  `/home/david/Origin90SR2DVD.iso`

Comment: @EliahKagan Just edited the question adding `postimage.org`  images

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Just edited the question adding postimage.org images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible that you had the `Origin90SR2DVD.iso` file in the location `/home/david` when the database file of `locate` (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`) was updated last time by `cron` (or by yourself). As `locate` just for the file names in the database file (thats why it is fast) while searching, you can consider it's technique not *live*.

Although `locate` is showing the location of the file, it is very possible that the file is not present there (might be removed or moved to somewhere else).

You have two ways to be sure of whats going on:

- You can update the `locate` database file by `sudo updatedb` and then run the same `locate` command.
- Alternately, you can use `find` to do a *live* search. To look for the file in your home directory recursively:

  ```bash
  find ~ -type f -iname 'Origin90SR2DVD.iso' -print -o -path ~/.gvfs -prune
  ```

  `-path ~/.gvfs -prune` (thanks to Eliah Kagan) is used so that we do not descend into `~/.gvfs` directory while searching. Otherwise we will get a distracting permission denied message, since the directory is owned by root. You can omit this (and see the message) by removing `-print -o -path ~/.gvfs -prune`.

  You can also look for all possible places in the filesystem hierarchy. Here I have considered few places that can contain the file, it will be unusual if your file is found under any other directory.

  ```bash
  sudo find /home /root /opt /usr/local /mnt -type f -iname 'Origin90SR2DVD.iso'
  ```

**EDIT :**

`locate`'s database is updated by `cron` on a daily basis. In my system it is run at 6:25 AM everyday (check your's on `/etc/crontab`).

Actually `anacron` will run the `cron` job to ensure that if the computer is Off at that time, the job will be run after the computer is turned On next time. If `anacron` is not available, `run-parts` will execute the files (including `mlocate`) in `/etc/cron.daily` directory only at the mentioned time.

Comment: I runned `sudo updatedb` , and then I wrote `locate Origin90SR2DVD.iso`. The output was:  `/home/david/Pictures/Origin90SR2DVD.iso`. So, before running `sudo updatedb`, the path was `/home/david/`.  Why the locate database was not up to date? Does it _need_  to be updated due to the fact that `locate` is not a _Live_  technique ? Thank you very very much!

Comment: @EliahKagan The `2>/dev/null` for `~` is for `~/.gvfs`..and yeah weird places could be ignored..i will make an edit..

Comment: @Dave Check my edits..

Comment: @EliahKagan: Seconded and edited :)

Comment: @heemayl I should mention, one disadvantage of `-print -o -name .gvfs -prune` is that if other, non-special files or directories called `.gvfs` have been created, they'll be pruned as well. If you're searching in just one user's home directory, you may want to append `-print -o -path ~/.gvfs -prune` instead, which also seems to work well. The only disadvantage is that you must give `.gvfs`'s path exactly as it appears relative to the directory you passed as the first argument to `find`, e.g., `find ~ -name foo -print -o -path ~/.gvfs -prune`, `find . -name foo -print -o -path ./.gvfs -prune`.

Comment: @EliahKagan It is highly unlikely that a user would have a file/directory named `.gvfs` somewhere else in `~` ..anyway keep it precise i will edit..thanks..

Comment: Agreed. And if they do, it's not really worse than how user-owned directories without read and execute permissions won't be checked. (That is, if someone wanted to make a `.tar` file or something where extraction produced folders whose contents wouldn't be found using this method, they already could.) And I like this better than `>/dev/null` as unrelated errors are shown. ...Btw, why use `-iname` instead of `-name`? The specific filename is known, after all. Also, you might want to explain `-type f`. It's OK here but I think [often doesn't do what people want](https://askubuntu.com/a/621094).

Comment: @EliahKagan Ooops..Thanks for the edit..something else was going on my mind then..anyway `-iname` was actually there to ensure that user does not make any mistake as there are so many uppercases-lowercases in the file name..

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo updatedb` to make sure your mlocate database is up to date.